# Setting up laravel project

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6

I have issue setting up existing laravel project on local machine.
My .env file goes like this

```
APP_NAME=DealWalletz
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=my-key
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
APP_URL=http://localhost

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=mydb
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=database
SESSION_LIFETIME=60
QUEUE_DRIVER=database

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379
```

The problem is it always ends up to view as shown up below even if I comment all the code in index function

[Error Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fCnE4.png)

This is my controller file. which has only this much code. I am using laravel 5.6 version

```php
public function index()
{
    $videos = QuickGuideVideo::get(['name', 'id']);

    $heading = ContentManagement::where('type', 'Vendor')->orderByDesc('id')->where('title', 'Logo Message')->first()->toArray();
    $vendor_logos = ContentManagement::where('type', 'Vendor')->orderByDesc('id')->where('title', 'Vendor Logo')->get();
    $webpage_headline = ContentManagement::where('type', 'Vendor')->orderByDesc('id')->where('title', 'Webpage Headline')->first();
    $webpage_customer = ContentManagement::where('type', 'Vendor')->orderByDesc('id')->where('title', 'Webpage Image Customer')->first();
    $webpage_image_1 = ContentManagement::where('type', 'Vendor')->orderByDesc('id')->where('title', 'Webpage Image 1')->first();
    $webpage_image_2 = ContentManagement::where('type', 'Vendor')->orderByDesc('id')->where('title', 'Webpage Image 2')->first();
    $webpage_image_3 = ContentManagement::where('type', 'Vendor')->orderByDesc('id')->where('title', 'Webpage Image 3')->first();
    $webpage_image_4 = ContentManagement::where('type', 'Vendor')->orderByDesc('id')->where('title', 'Webpage Image 4')->first();

    return view('home', compact('videos', 'heading', 'vendor_logos', 'webpage_headline', 'webpage_customer', 'webpage_image_1', 'webpage_image_2', 'webpage_image_3', 'webpage_image_4'));
}
```

The view file is here which always ends up into error
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hM_nf_2HUTL9jrQasAXpx8fxghrQwCwW/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Can you put the code from home.blade.php please as this is the file that is being complained about in the error

Comment: Route goes here

Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');

Comment: I am new to laravel I think i have not installed it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are having is from this line

```
<p><span style="margin-right: 5px">Welcome to </span> {!! $heading['description'] !!}</p>
```

When it is loading this view, the heading variable is not available. Two things I would say probably cause this.

Either the route you are going to, is not running this controller for the view. So maybe you have another route?
You can find this out by running this command in your terminal. (Make sure you are in the root of your project)

```
php artisan route:list
```

If there is only one route for `/` I recommend checking the output from your `ContentManagement` model.

In your controller check the output from $heading variable by adding this line underneath

```
$heading = ContentManagement::where('type','Vendor')->orderByDesc('id')->where('title','Logo Message')->first()->toArray();
dd($heading);
```

Another thing to note, you are calling `toArray()` on `first()`. If your result is null, you will get an error here, so should always check to see if you have a result

Comment: Thanks for the update.
The problem is if I "dd($heading); " it ends up on view not showing the same error as posted in starting.
Even if I echo anything at the start of the function and comment rest then the same error occurs.
The code doesn't show the same error as posted in starting.
What I am doing wrong, I can't figure out.

Comment: Okay so to confirm, can you show me the output from the DD please. I think that will mean it is using that controller. Have you tried wrapping $heading['description'] in `{{ }}` rather than `{!! !!}` It may not make a difference but good to check

Comment: After DD it shows the same error as posted for undefined variable $heading.
{{ }} rather than {!! !!} : this makes no difference

Comment: Okay just to confirm with the `dd($heading);` you are still getting the exact same error? If that is the case it means your route is not hitting your controller to declare the variables

Comment: What did you get from running `php artisan route:list`

Comment: ```| GET|HEAD                               | /                                                |                                             | App\Http\Controllers\HomeController@index                                                            | web,guest```

This is what reflects in php artisan route:list for default page

Yes, I am getting the same error when hitting ```dd($heading);```

Comment: Do you have xdebug to step through the request and see where it goes instead of the controller? It could be due to one of your middleware checking if you are authenticated and sending you to the homepage.